# How do i change the column names in a result set and create a new result set in PHP with modified column names

Tags: php, names

Example: **my current result set:**

```
array(7) {[0]=>array(2) 

{ ["class_id"]=>string(1) "1"["class"]=>string(3)"1st"}

{ ["class_id"]=>string(1) "2"["class"]=>string(3)"2nd"}

{ ["class_id"]=>string(1) "3"["class"]=>string(3)"3rd"}
```

**I want a new result set as :**

```
array(7) {[0]=>array(2) 

{ ["new_id"]=>string(1) "1"["new_class"]=>string(3)"1st"}

{ ["new_id"]=>string(1) "2"["new_class"]=>string(3)"2nd"}

{ ["new_id"]=>string(1) "3"["new_class"]=>string(3)"3rd"}
```

I dont want this to affect the column names in my database. only the result set.

Comment: The result is an array changing the array won't affect your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function rename_key(&$array, $oldkey, $newkey) {
// remember here we send value by reference using `&`
    if(array_key_exists($oldkey,$array))
    {
        $array[$newkey] = &$array[$oldkey];
        unset($array[$oldkey]);
    }
    return $array;
}

foreach($input as $k)
{
    rename_key($k, 'class_id', 'new_id');
    rename_key($k, 'class', 'new_class');
    $output[]=$k;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($output);
```

Answer (score 3):

Show us your query.. If you're doing, for example, the following query:

```
SELECT class_id, class FROM table;
```

Change it to this:

```
SELECT class_id AS new_id, class AS new_class FROM table;
```

Changing it in the query is hands-down the best way to do it, as you're not having to do any extra work within PHP, however you could also amend them in PHP, of course.

```
// where $resultset is your original results..
foreach ($resultset as &$result) {
    $result_ = array('new_id' => $result['class_id'], 'new_class' => $result['class']);
    $result = $result_;
}
```

Note that neither of these methods would affect your database columns. The only way to do that would be via an `ALTER|MODIFY TABLE` statement.

Comment: when i var_dump my new result set, i only get { ["new_id"]=>string(1) "3"["new_class"]=>string(3)"3rd"} . But { ["new_id"]=>string(1) "1"["new_class"]=>string(3)"1st"}

{ ["new_id"]=>string(1) "2"["new_class"]=>string(3)"2nd"}
 are missing..!

Comment: @Rahul_2289 With which method? Use the query variant.

Comment: @rudi_visser: the php method !

Comment: @Rahul_2289 Well try the query method, it's 1000% better than the PHP method. Are you sure you're `var_dump`ing `$resultset` and not `$result`?

Answer (score 0):

In foreach cycle. Create a new array with needed to you colums from existing result set.